# Can you increment a date that you are adding as a field to an MSWord document

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I am using MSWord to create a document to plan my week, I want to automatically update a date range automatically before I print it.

e.g. for today's date I'd want to display

> 18/06/2012 - 29/06/2012

I have inserted a Field with DATE for the first half, but want to automatically calculate the second by inserting e.g. `DATE+11`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a lot more complicated than it appears.

This link gives instructions on how to do it:
http://www.gmayor.com/insert_a_date_other_than_today.htm

And because this is so complicated, here is a Word document with macros for various date functions:
http://www.gmayor.com/Zips/DateCalc.zip

Comment: Not so complicated for the single case:
`Sub IncrementDateByElevenDays()
Selection.InsertDateTime Format((Date + 11), "dd/MM/yyyy")
End Sub`

Comment: Unfortunately, using a macro doesn't automatically update the field when opening the document. Is there a way to do this?